# put check of a field in the tab

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

i want to ask your help from you.

I want to mark an existing field within a tab, the display name is project.

When selecting the template field, at that moment it brings the information from the tasks tab, at that moment I want it to have the check marked.

Here I attach an image.
[image]

Here I attach the codes that I have tried to use, but that has not worked.

These are the 3 commands I used, but it doesn't work.

1.- code

```
    [PXDBBool()]

    [PXDefault(true, PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Default")]
    protected virtual void PMTask_IsDefault_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
    {

    }
```

2.- code

```
    protected virtual void _(Events.FieldDefaulting<PMTask, PMTask.isDefault> e)
    {
        if (e.Row!=null)
        {
            /*defaul check, It doesn't work*/
            e.Cache.SetValue<PMTask.isDefault>(e.Row, true);
        }
    }
```

3.- code

```
     protected virtual void _(Events.FieldUpdated<PMProject, PMProject.templateID> e)
    {
        if (e.Row!=null)
        {
            /*defaul check, It doesn't work*/
            var pmtask = Base.Tasks.Current;
            pmtask.IsDefault = true;
        }
    }
```

Let me know what I'm doing wrong or maybe I'm doing something I shouldn't, thanks everyone.

Comment: When debugging does the code not execute or does it execute but the values does not update?

Comment: if it runs, but the change is lost, it seems that tab is very special.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below event handler. It will set the checkbox to true if the Template ID is set to a value and to false if the Template ID is cleaned.

```
protected virtual void _(Events.FieldUpdated<PMProject, PMProject.templateID> e)
{
    if (e.Row is PMProject row)
    {
        e.Cache.SetValue<PMTask.isDefault>(e.Row, row.TemplateID!=null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried adding this code you provided and it doesn't work, thank you very much.